# Occasionally online app data synchronisation

Tags: wpf, silverlight, sqlite, html, synchronization

I am writing an application which consists of a master "server" database (most probably sqlite) and a client side replica with client specific records (again, Sqlite). The clients may only be online occasionally or may be on slow 3G connections; I need a solution to reliably synchronise content either on demand or at scheduled intervals. The client application could be either WPF/Silverlight or HTML5 (hence the preference for sqlite).

I've been looking at the Microsoft Synchronisation framework 2.0 but obviously this won't work for HTML5 and I'd like to keep the architecture as consistent as possible. Any other ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Bidirectional synchronization?

Comment: Nope, one way, server to client (content will largely just be product data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Rhino Service bus combined with an offline cache - Ayende has published a very nice demo of how to do it on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796225.aspx). (And to me, it sounds like you're facing many of the same problems - I don't know enough about HTML5 to see if it would work against that, though)

Comment: Nice article and certainly a potential solution, I don't think this would work for HTML5 however I think this may be a non-issue since mobile clients could work "connected" if needs be. I'll do some more investigation.